# Await New Promise Not Working When Getting Url Photo From Firebase Storage

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-firestore, async-await, firebase-storage

I Want to get data contacts from firebase store and then get photo of contacts from firestore storage.

```
get_contact  = async () => {
let contacts = [];
let campaignsRef = await firestore().collection('users').doc(global.iduser).collection("contacts").get();
for (let campaign of campaignsRef.docs) {
    let tasksRef = firestore().collection('users').doc(campaign.data().uid).get();
    await tasksRef
    .then(DocumentSnapshot => {
      let data = DocumentSnapshot.data();
      let photo =  new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        storage()
        .refFromURL('gs://think-ce51b.appspot.com/profiledefault.jpg')
        .getDownloadURL()
        .then(url => {
          resolve(url);
        })
        .catch(error => {
          return reject(error);
        });
      });    
      console.log(photo);
      contacts.push({
        'key': data.uid,
        'fullname': data.fullname,
        'profilephoto': photo,
      });
    })
    .catch(error => {
      setInitializing(false);
    });
}
setdataContacts(contacts);
setInitializing(false);}
```

I Can get data contacts from DocumenSnapshot. But when I want get url from firebase storage, photo return null/{"_U": 0, "_V": 0, "_W": null, "_X": null}. I think new promise in varible photo not function correctly.

How I can push to contacts only after photo get url?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are quite a few problems with your code. The ones I quickly spotted:

1. The `getDownloadURL` method already returns a promise, so you don't need to create your own.
2. You should not mix `await` and `then` in code. Unless you intricately know what you're doing, it's best to stick to one or the other.

If we fix these two problems in your code, we end up with:

```
get_contact  = async () => {
  let contacts = [];
  let campaignsRef = await firestore().collection('users').doc(global.iduser).collection("contacts").get();
  for (let campaign of campaignsRef.docs) {
    let tasksDoc = await firestore().collection('users').doc(campaign.data().uid).get();
    let data = tasksDoc.data();
    let url = await storage()
        .refFromURL('gs://think-ce51b.appspot.com/profiledefault.jpg')
        .getDownloadURL()
    contacts.push({
      'key': data.uid,
      'fullname': data.fullname,
      'profilephoto': photo,
    });
  }
  setdataContacts(contacts);
  setInitializing(false);
}
```

There may be more problems with the code, but this is a good starting point.